# Can't find upgrade to 12.04, Update manager doesn't seem to detect it

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, updates, update-manager

Update manager doesn't seem to want to find the upgrade.  I have tried "update-manager -d" "do-release-upgrade" is cd going to be my only route?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean it first

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```